# Update TexStudio

Tags: synaptic, latex, text-editor

I'm using TexStudio on Ubuntu 14.04.
I installed it via the Synaptic package manager.

I noticed that the most recent version in synaptic is 2.6.6 but on texstudio's website they show their current version as 2.9.4.

The 2.6.6 is from December of 2013 and the current version is from March 2015. Is there a way to let someone know of this so that they can fix it in order to get Synaptic to show a more recent version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [official launchpad source page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texstudio), the newer version(s) are in fact available for Ubuntu Vivid and Wily:

[image]

I suppose you are on Trusty, were no one has considered important/necessary to make a backport of the new versions. If you want, you can file a question there and see if the developers are available to percolate the updates down to Trusty --- but that's probably difficult (the idea of a LTS is to stay stable as much as possible).

But if you look more throughly, [you can find a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~blahota/+archive/ubuntu/texstudio/) that seems to provide the last version:

[image]

Which provides the 2.9.4 version to Precise, Trusty, Vivid and Utopic.

You can find information on features, risks and how to use a PPA in [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: Great Answer! Thank you. Will I have to uninstall the current version before installing the PPA?

Comment: @Miguel no, not needed. After installing the PPA it should offer the update.